# Publishing messages to AWS SNS with Micronaut and Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, amazon-sns, micronaut-aws

I'm tryin to send a list of objects to an SNS topic, with Micronaut and Kotlin.

Following the documentation https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-aws/latest/guide/#sdkv2

1. I added `implementation("io.micronaut.aws:micronaut-aws-sdk-v2")`.
2. `accessKeyId, secretKey, sessionToken and region` to the application yml file.
3. Added `implementation("software.amazon.awssdk:sns")`
   After which you should have these beans:

- `software.amazon.awssdk.services.sns.SnsAsyncClientBuilder`
- `software.amazon.awssdk.services.sns.SnsAsyncClient`
  I'm assuming asynchronous calls...

Now it's not clear what else should I do how to create the clients to make the calls to
publish a message.

I was inclined to use **Netty** but what about **URLConnection** ??
Whats the next step in here?

I've also found another article but they use Java https://agorapulse.github.io/micronaut-aws-sdk/#_simple_notification_service_sns
it uses another package

Is there any example of how to do this? can you do this with Micronaut?